# How to Bold first line of :before content in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox

I'm using a framework where I can add attributes to an element, but can't add dom elements myself. What I'm trying to do is add two lines of content to the `:before` pseudo-element, then make the first line bold.

```css
[data-text]::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  white-space: pre;
}

[data-text]::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div data-text="Here's some text.
Here's a new line with more text.">
  ...
</div>
```

This effect works exactly as I want it to in Chrome, Edge and IE11 (which was a shock), but not in Firefox (also a shock). Why does Firefox not bold the first line while the other browsers do? How do I get the first line bolded?

Comment: Note: two colons are now required for pseudo-elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: Updated code to two colons - no change.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply it was a fix to the problem. I'm just giving you a heads up about valid CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Hey can you try like this;

```css
[data-text]::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  /*display: block;*/
  white-space: pre;
}

[data-text]::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div data-text="Here's some text.
Here's a new line with more text.
">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, it seems to only work in Firefox when the computed value of the `display` property for `::before` is `inline`.